# подключение FFmpegMediaPlayer

Tags: android

Не могу разобраться, как подключить библиотеку FFmpegMediaPlayer к проекту. Я так понял там нужно разбиратся в NDK. Кто может просто объяснить, как такое делать?

Comment: Проект на гитхабе https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer, и в нем же есть Demo Application. Посмотрите, как он подключен к Demo Application, сделайте точно так же

Comment: там в build пишет compile project(':library'), папка library занимает 100 мб. Это нормально?

Comment: да, нормально в случае с подключением NDK. кроме того, это же пример от разработчика! Куда уж тут *нормальнее*